# Is grabbing the shoulder pads defensive holding?

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl

During the Monday night game between Green Bay and Detroit on [14 October 2019](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201910140gnb.htm), Detroit’s Trey Flowers was twice penalized for “Illegal Hands to the Face” when he wasn’t really touching the face but was instead grabbing the shoulder pads under the chin. The [result of the penalties was a first down](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/24159/1723), both happening at crucial moments for the Packers.

The ESPN announcer made a big deal about how the calls were wrong and that it affected the outcome of the game. However, a friend of mine pointed out that although “Illegal Hands to the Face” is not the correct call, it should have been penalized as “Defensive Holding,” which results in the same 5 yards and First Down.

Is this true? Is grabbing and holding the shoulder pads under someone’s chin considered Defensive Holding?

Comment: Booger mentioned that hands to the neck is covered under the umbrella of this penalty.  I assume in the eyes of the officials it appeared that Flowers' hand was close to the neck in either case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using equipment to pressure the face or neck is hands to the face.  It is quite common to see a defensive lineman get a hands to the face penalty when hitting the players neck.   The other option the ref has is to give him a misconduct which is 15.

Also both lines can hold the shoulder pads in the front chest area.  I don't think you can find this in a rulebook but it is in referee guides.   However neither side can pull the other using the pads or anything else and this is why holding - on either side - is called 98% of the time.

In summary this situation didn't seem like defensive holding.   It seemed like a personal foul - hands to face.   In that umbrella it is touching the face mask, chin, or neck or using any equipment to aid in that.   Again I am not sure you will see all of this referenced in a rulebook unless it has been annotated recently.   This is something you will see in referee guides, especially in the NFL where they have a rulebook that covers the main things and then half of the other stuff - like this - is secretly given to their referee crews and is generally non-public (think the catch rule and current PI calls).